# What does "modulo conformance" phrase mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, translation

[Standards version switches in the compiler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/) page has the following text:

> The /std:c++14 switch enables the set of C++14 features implemented by the Visual C++ compiler, modulo conformance bug fixes and ongoing feature work (such as for constexpr, expression SFINAE, 2-phase name lookup, etc.)

I treated this text as: "/std:c++14 switch enables some set of C++14 features, **including** bug fixes and changes made for constexpr, expression SFINAE, 2-phase name lookup, etc". My practice has shown that I was wrong. In particular, "2-phase name lookup" isn't affected by `/std:c+14`.

In a topic devoted to Visual C++ I got an explanation, that:

> The wording you quoted means it enables C++14 features *except for* constexpr, expression SFINAE, 2-phase name lookup, etc., which are not yet implemented.

I neither could ask English language specific question in the programming topic, nor write a private message to the man.

Therefore, I asked my question here: why the first quote in this post means the second quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *modulo* can have a meaning of "ignoring" or "except".
It's has been discussed on [ELU, here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70018/meaning-of-modulo-the-fact).

> The pattern
>
> > X modulo Y
>
> is an informal but common parlance in technical, especially mathematically, oriented talk. It is used to mean informally
>
> > X, ignoring Y.
>
> For example,
>
> > The rocket design was flawless, modulo the toxic waste produced by its fuel.

It also has [these related meanings](http://www.yourdictionary.com/modulo)

> - Correcting or adjusting for something, as by leaving something out of account:
>     *This proposal is the best so far, modulo the fact that parts of it need modification.*
> - Except for differences accounted for by.
>     *"A is the same as B modulo C" means A is the same as B except for differences accounted for by C.*